# How to remove arrow head of Refresh Indicator widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a mobile developer and now I'm making an app by flutter.
I need to pull to refresh feature in my app and I found there is a widget called refresh indicator, which is just fit for my app.
But I also found there were some problems.

The first one is it seems I can't remove arrow head style. When I saw videos or even their official website, they look like they don't have arrow head yet. But for now, it has. I suspect that widget was updated, and got the arrow like head. But what if there is someone who don't want that change?

And the second thing is it seems I can't remove its shadow as it has by default as well.

Those seem like trivial, but I want to build my app as exactly what I designed.

If there's someone to solve these issues, would you help me? I hope there's a solution with Theme or anything.

Thank you for reading, and looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Which Flutter version do you use? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html The example here has no "arrow head"

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Yeah, you're right. There's no properties related to arrow head. But it seems like an arrow on your phone, and I found 'arrow head scale' in pre-defined dart file.

Comment: Hmm, i would check this package out https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator - shouldn't be hard to duplicate the refresh indicator without elevation and a different icon

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems like I have no choice but pick it.